# Android notification management

Tags: android

Does any body know the name of android class that manage icons display in notification bar ?
I'm not talking about adding an icon in notification bar, I want the one that display already added icons in the notification bar.
My problem is the following:
In notification bar, only 9 icons can be displayed. And when we have more than 9 icons, for example we have 11 icons, 8 icons are displayed in notification bar and a notification overlay icon will bes displayed containing 3. My problem is when I have 10 icons, the overlay icon is not displayed and either the 10th icon.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. The constructor for the Notification class already has this info. Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);  What are you looking for ?

Comment: well I'am not talking about that, I think it is StatusBarService class in framework

Comment: Please update your question and clarify that. You will receive better answers.